# Firebase orderByChild

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a weird interaction when I'm using `orderByChild` with Firebase.

I have this object in Firebase:

```
[{
    "date": "2016-10-28 21:45:30",
    "price": "6700",
    "id": "2423267",
    "title": "Some Title",
    "description": "Some Desc"
}]
```

Then I'm doing a query like this:

```
this.databaseRef.startAt(query).orderByChild('date').limitToFirst(50).once('value);
```

If I do `orderByChild('title')` or any other field that is a string, and the query is for example "Some" then I get the right results back.

But if I do `orderByChild('date')` and the same query, I don't get any results.

I have also tried putting the date as a timestamp, that doesn't work also.

I think that there is something wrong when doing `queryByChild` and that child is a number, but the query is a string, or the other way around.

How would I fix this, I need the results order-ed by the date, but queried by the title?

Answer (score 0):

please try below, your `query` varibale must be date

```
this.databaseRef.orderByChild('date').startAt(query).limitToFirst(50)
```